# Excel:- maintain the relative positions of chart & hand-drawn-lines

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2007, excel-2003, office-2007

I have a stock-chart in Excel.
Certain highs & lows are connected by drawing a line manually (from the drawing toolbar).
When I change the data-range or resize the chart, the lines obviously stay in their original position.
And the bars in chart get resized.

Is there any way to maintain the relative positions of chart & hand-drawn-lines?
Maybe, merging the bars in chart with the lines drawn by hand?

Thanks,

Vineet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for same.

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-charting/835738-grouping-chart-and-lines.html?p=2812431

-- Vineet

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon because they are subject to link rot. Please include at least some sample code so anyone else who finds this answer doesn't have to go somewhere else.